# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'action.routeName') while using React-Navigation and Redux for React-Native App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm getting the following error (articulated above and noted in the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTyvL.png)) for a React Native app.  I'm implementing react-navigation into redux.

I also haven't put in any redirects into the app yet.  I'm planning on calling NavigationActions to redirect to the Login screen based on the LoggedIn status which is being configured by a separate reducer that manages the state for the user.

The app was working properly when I did not have redux managing the navigation state.  I decided to put the navigation state into redux when I realized I'll need some redirects based on the user logged in status which is being managed by the redux.

My code is as follows:

## src/navigators/middleware.js

```
import {
  createNavigationPropConstructor,
  createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware,
} from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';

// building redux utils for navigation
export const middleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
  'root',
  state => state.nav,
);

export const navigationPropConstructor = createNavigationPropConstructor('root');
```

## src/navigators/AppNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Welcome from '../screens/Welcome';
import Dashboard from '../screens/Dashboard';
import Login from '../screens/Login';

routeNames = {
  Welcome: { screen: Welcome },
  Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
  Login: { screen: Login },
};

config = {
  navigationOptions: ({
    header: 'null',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
    },
    headerLeft: null,
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontSize: 30,
      fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',
    },
  }),
};

export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(routeNames, config);
```

## src/navigators/AppWithInternalState.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';
import { AppNavigator } from './AppNavigator';
import { initializeListeners } from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';
import { navigationPropConstructor } from './middleware';

class AppWithInternalState extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    nav: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    initializeListeners('root', this.props.nav);
  };

  render = () => {
    const { dispatch, nav } = this.props;
    const navigation = navigationPropConstructor(dispatch, nav);
    return <AppNavigator navigation={ navigation } />;
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  nav: state.nav,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithInternalState);
```

## src/reducers/navReducers

```
import { AppNavigator } from '../navigators/AppNavigator';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const router = AppNavigator.router;

const firstAction = router.getActionForPathAndParams('Dashboard');
const tempNavState = router.getStateForAction(firstAction);

const secondAction = router.getActionForPathAndParams('Login');
const initialNavState = router.getStateForAction(secondAction, tempNavState);

export default navReducer = (state=initialNavState, action) => {
  let nextState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Login':
      nextState = router.getStateForAction(
        NavigationActions.back(),
        state,
      );
      break;
    default:
      nextState = router.getStateForAction(action.state);
      break;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this myself.  Looks like there is an issue with react-navigation when using createNavigationPropConstructor. 
 This will not be solved until react-navigation@2.03 is released. 
 Until then, create your own navigation prop:

```
import { createReduxBoundAddListener } from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';

const navigation = {
  dispatch,
  state: nav,
  addListener: createReduxBoundAddListener('root'),
};
```

You can see and track the issue here:  https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4320